# Codename One Send Build Error

Tags: android, ssl, intellij-idea, build, codenameone

I am investigating possible cross-platform solutions for my company and I am trying Codename One right now. I really like it but today i created a hello world project and I am getting an error when I try to the build server. I have also tried an iOS build and I get the same error. Here is the exception I am getting:

```
Jun 17, 2016 9:02:32 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

This is my android settings in build.xml:

```
<target name="build-for-android-device" depends="clean,copy-android-override,copy-libs,jar,clean-override">
    <codeNameOne 
        jarFile="${dist.jar}"
        displayName="${codename1.displayName}"
        packageName = "${codename1.packageName}"
        mainClassName = "${codename1.mainName}"
        version="${codename1.version}"
        icon="${codename1.icon}"
        vendor="${codename1.vendor}"
        subtitle="${codename1.secondaryTitle}"

        targetType="android"
        keystoreAlias="${codename1.android.keystoreAlias}"
        keystore="${codename1.android.keystore}"
        certPassword="${codename1.android.keystorePassword}"
        automated="${automated}"
        />
</target>
```

And I think this might be unrelated as its for a build I am not concerned with and is probably not getting parsed but in my windows portion of build.xml

```
<target name="build-for-windows-device" depends="clean,copy-windows-override,copy-libs,jar,clean-override">
    <codeNameOne 
        jarFile="${dist.jar}"
        displayName="${codename1.displayName}"
        packageName = "${codename1.packageName}"
        mainClassName = "${codename1.mainName}"
        version="${codename1.version}"
        icon="${codename1.icon}"
        vendor="${codename1.vendor}"
        subtitle="${codename1.secondaryTitle}"

        certificate="${codename1.windows.certificate}"           <-- these lines are red indicating the properties cannot be found
        certPassword="${codename1.windows.certificatePassword}"  <--

        targetType="windows"
        automated="${automated}"
        />
</target>
```

It was working fine yesterday but now it is not. I am using Intellij Idea as my IDE. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE1**
I have installed the certificate for codenameone.com into Intellij and the Java cert store and I am still having this issue.

**UPDATE2**
I tried it on Netbeans as well and got the same error and was able to get the whole log.

```
build-for-android-device:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1433)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1431)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.login(BuildProcess.java:119)
at com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask.execute(CodeNameOneBuildTask.java:192)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
... 35 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 41 more
C:\dev\projects\codename-one\CodenameOne\build.xml:309: Error in server build process
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why this will happen to you as I've been building for a couple of years with no such issue. One thing to notice is that the build servers also hide the "real" URL which is https://codename-one.appspot.com/ and that might might be the certificate that is failing.

It's also possible that the [recent proxy changes](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/unskin-proxy-support.html) triggered this. Make sure you configured this properly in the simulator.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance here. I updated the cert for codenameone.appspot.com and now it works perfectly.

Comment: That's an odd issue as the appspot certificate is a Google issued certificate. Do you have a very restrictive corporate security policy? If so this might be worth covering in a guide.

Comment: Yes i worked with the IT department to get the issue fixed. But now I'm trying to build again for the first time in a few weeks and I am having the same error. I tried to log in through the preferences and updated the cert for the above url and I still have problems.